# Mysql get max row and min row from group of each row

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL table with employees attendance. first row of a day of employee treating as in time and last row of a day of employee treating as out time. I am trying to select first and last (min time and max time) from attendance table. It should give me two row sets. but my query not giving me as i expecting the result.

Table (Attendance)

[image: Attendance Table with employees attendance (IMAGE)]

My Query

```
select *, min(attdate) as intime, max(attdate) as outtime  from attendance where empid=1
```

But above query not giving me as expected result. My output should be in below image. Please suggest me the query or give me hint to achieve given output.

[image: Attendance out put should be (IMAGE)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done by sub queries in where conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM attendance AS c WHERE empid=1 and (
attdate=( select min(attdate) from attendance where attendance.empid=c.empid )
 or attdate=( select max(attdate) from attendance where attendance.empid=c.empid )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't offer window functions, so it's a bit more difficult here. You can use exists :

```
Select * from yourtable t
Where not exists (select 1 from yourtable s
                              Where t.empid = s.empid and
                                         (s.attndate < t.attndate or s.attndate > t.attndate))
```

Though it seems you need to add another condition t.date = s.date unless you have only 1 day records stored there